# How to Convert Hexe to ImageView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, hex

```
String photoByte2 = "FFD8FFE000104A46494600010101000000000000FFE2021C4943435...."
```

this is not whole hex code;

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte2.getBytes(), 0,photoByte2.length());
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

i want convert above Base16 or Hex code to Image View in my android Project?but i dont have idea what can i do...

Comment: notice that my image save in my table as Base16 and i want read it from database and convert to imageview...not problem at reading from db but in convert :((( !!

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624203/converting-a-hex-string-to-an-image-file

Answer (score 1):

First convert your Hex to  array of int (Int[]) and from that u can get bitmap by

```
bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(int[] intarray, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)
```

Comment: all right,how can i convert my Hex to Int[]?! do u have any link ?

Comment: here you have different conversion check this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hex-to-decimal)